# How to resize Ubuntu partition without re installing Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, 13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. When I type `df -h`, the terminal shows the following information

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        28G   26G     0 100% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           794M  872K  793M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.9G  224K  3.9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   48K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda8        35G  102M   33G   1% /boot
/dev/sda5        69G   18G   51G  27% /media/user/Chinnu
/dev/sda2       130G   40G   90G  31% /media/user/CCCA371ACA37006E
/dev/sda1        70G   50G   21G  72% /media/user/76E66C99E66C5AFF 
/dev/sda3       130G   12G  118G  10% /media/user/jinju
```

I hope 28G is the size given to Ubuntu.

When I took "About this computer" menu item. it shows that

> DISK : 66.2 GB

But I need some more GBs in Ubuntu. Is it possible to resize my Ubuntu partition without reinstalling?

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

You can resize and create new partitions. Run it from live CD/DVD because can't  modify in-use partition.

[image]